# How do i start at the end of an array and work my way to the beginning?

Tags: java

I'm trying to produce code that will search for an element starting at the end of an array and work it's towards the beginning until i find what I am looking for. so far I have this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
     for (int i = randomList.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
             if (randomList[i].equals(findThis))
                {
                    System.out.println("The index of what you're looking for in the array is: " + i);

                }                
            }
```

When I compile and run this, it produces the same answer as this:

```
     for (int j = 0; j < randomList.length; j++)
            {
            if (randomList[j].equals(findThis))
                {
                    System.out.println("What you're looking for is located at this index: " + j);
                }           
            }
```

which is weird because it is starting at the front of the array and working its way to the end. I am grateful for all help!

Comment: I don't see how the first iteration could go in the same direction than the second one. What makes you think it does ?

Comment: That seems to be right - the thing is you're printing out the index where the element is found. If the array doesn't change, then it will always find it in the same index, no matter the direction in which you search.

Comment: do you actually have duplicates in the array?

Comment: Well, both the loop of course would give the same output. The index value doesn't change regardless of how you are iterating over your array. And you are printing the index only. So, the value is at index 2, it will match at index = 2 only.

Comment: Oh WOW! I'm a fool. So, how would i change the code to show which iteration is faster at finding a specific element in an array?

Comment: @jordan measure the timing of doing it several times. The test time should be in the order of seconds to minimise noise.

Comment: @JanDvorak how would i go about measuring the timing?

Comment: @jordan time_end - time_start. Look at `System.getNanoTime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the index of the found element, which is going to be the same in either direction (i.e. `array[4]` will be the same regardless of how you search)

If you want the count in the other direction, you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomList.length; i++)
{
  if (randomList[randomList.length - i - 1].equals(findThis))
    {
      System.out.println("The count from the back of the array is: " + i);
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick way to get the index is to do something like this:

```
int idx = randomList.lastIndexOf(findThis);
```

Simple, one line of code that will return the last index of the given object.  There is also this if you want the first index:

```
int idx = randomList.indexOf(findThis);
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

```
for (int i = randomList.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = randomList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

But otherwise it looks correct; are you sure you are cleaning / rebuilding correctly with your IDE?

If you can, provide additional context such as where the code is being run, what your data is, and what the expected vs. actual results are.

Comment: Yeah! these amazing comments, like yours, pointed out why i was really confused. I was confusing the count with the index! heh. But, i'm a novice trying to understand how to compare which method of searching through an array would be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

You will only get different answer if the searched value exist more than once in your array.
BTW. your condition should be i >= 0 if you want to check first element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of:

["Dog", "Cat", "Marsupial", "Dr. Pepper", "Pepsi"]

then the index of "Dr. Pepper" will always be 3 no matter the direction in which you search.

EDIT: We use 0 indexed arrays here. :D

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying `i` and `j` values which are the position of the element in the array, when the element of the array is equal to the element you are seeking for.

Your code is correct you are just returning the index of the element you are searching for so starting from the beginning or the end it will return the same index (the same element position) unless you have more than one element that is equal to the element you are seeking for then you will notice the difference.

in order to understand what is going on you should change your code like below :

```
 for (int i = randomList.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
         System.out.println("Actual index =" + i);
         if (randomList[i].equals(findThis))
            {
                System.out.println("The index of what you're looking for in the array is: " + i);

            }                
        }
```

When I compile and run this, it produces the same answer as this:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < randomList.length; j++)
        {
         System.out.println("Actual index =" + j);
         if (randomList[j].equals(findThis))
            {
                System.out.println("What you're looking for is located at this index: " + j);
            }           
        }
```